# MySQLi: Advance query to limit the number of products for the price range

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this possible to make in the MySQLi query parameter to set the following thing:

For example: I have a product table with various products with different prices

Table: products

```
id  name     price
1   pen      10
2   banana   50
3   potato   10
5   apple    20
6   guaba    30
7   papa     30
8   salt     80
9   butter   25
10  cheese   10
```

I want to limit the price range and product range in the MySQLi statement.
For example: When I want to show 5 products those prices are accumulative to 100 or near 100, it will fetch any 5 products from database that's price accumulative to 100.

Again, when I want to show 2 products those price are accumulate to 100 or near 100, it will fetch any two products those prices match to accumulative 100 or near 100.

I have learned that it is possible to make the price range by following way; But I am not sure if I also can limit the product number for those price range.

For price range; I can do by:

```
SELECT id, name, price
FROM (
   SELECT id, name, price,
          @cumSum:= @cumSum + price AS cumSum
   FROM products, (SELECT @cumSum:=0) var
   ORDER BY id ) t
WHERE cumSum <= 100
```

But how can I limit the number of products for the price range?

Comment: Do you want any five products or do you want them in order by id?

Comment: Is it possible a product has price higher than query parameter? In this case : `cumSum` in your query.

Comment: order by can be any thing, id or price. just need the logic for product limit, no problem for ascending or descending . just need to specify the number of products and accumulative price range

Comment: And what if user need to show 5 products with accumulative price 40 or near 40? since you don't have products with prices lower than 10?

Comment: There will be more products also 5, 10, 8 prices. Those are only for example products, not limit to those 10 products and that prices.

Comment: Interesting question. This would be need a lot of code.

Comment: What code you are thinking to be a lot? in sql or php ? Can't I implement the logic in sql statement?

Comment: Both, sql and php. Actually, I have no idea to solve this using sql. But, php would, with a lot of code. I marked this as favorited, and will be back if I have clue. Because I need this too..

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to find 5 prices that sum of them is nearest to 100:

<kbd>[`SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d0c6/7)</kbd>

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (
SELECT 
    CONCAT('|', t1.id, '|', t2.id, '|', t3.id, '|', t4.id, '|', t5.id, '|')
FROM 
    t t1
    JOIN
    t t2 ON t1.id <> t2.id
    JOIN
    t t3 ON t1.id <> t3.id AND t2.id <> t3.id
    JOIN
    t t4 ON t1.id <> t4.id AND t2.id <> t4.id AND t3.id <> t4.id
    JOIN
    t t5 ON t1.id <> t5.id AND t2.id <> t5.id AND t3.id <> t5.id AND t4.id <> t5.id
ORDER BY
    ABS(t1.price + t2.price + t3.price + t4.price + t5.price - 100)
LIMIT 1) LIKE CONCAT('%|', id ,'|%');
```

Result is:

```
id  name    price
1   pen     10
2   banana  50
3   potato  10
5   apple   20
10  cheese  10
```

And for 2 prices:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (
SELECT 
    CONCAT('|', t1.id, '|', t2.id, '|')
FROM 
    t t1
    JOIN
    t t2 ON t1.id <> t2.id
ORDER BY
    ABS(t1.price + t2.price - 100)
LIMIT 1) LIKE CONCAT('%|', id ,'|%');
```

Comment: This is good solution. But how to make another prices without rewrite query? I mean use it as variable. This is for 2 or 5 prices, what if 3,4 etc?

Comment: Yes, your answer is nice; but my query need to be dynamic. number of product limit and price range will come as variable will vary time to time, 5, and 2 are for example.  these two condition thing will come as bellow: $number_product="5"; $price_range="100"; for example, it will vary

Comment: @ZahirulHaque I think, you can use this. And do some improvement on php to make the query dynamic.

Comment: Hi, It is nice code anyway; but it becomes very slow when I run the code for 4 or 5 prices. Is there any optimized way so that it becomes fast?

Comment: I'm not so good in query-optimizing, I suggest you to ask another question about your query performance ;).